# ResourceBundle returns NULL without any errors being raised

Tags: php, resourcebundle, icu, intl

For internationalized data it would be great to work with the `\ResourceBundle` class from PHP's "intl" extension.

I got the extension running (PHP 5.3.4; Windows) and created a .dat file using the [ICU Data Library Customizer](http://apps.icu-project.org/datacustom/)*, but I don't get the expected result from the resource bundle class.

Now I do this

```
$bundle   = '/var/www/libs/icudt48l.dat';
$resource = new \ResourceBundle('en_US', $bundle, true);
var_dump($resource, is_file($bundle)); //--> NULL, TRUE
```

The problem is `$resource` returns NULL without any errors being raised. What's going on?

*(Only the last two data sections were checked—base data is always included—and I exported it as ICU4C)

Comment: You might consider reading CLDR data directly as that is where ICU data comes from - the internal format of ICU4C's data shouldn't be relied on. May I ask, what is the purpose of your customization? It might be better to implement your component in terms of the intl extension, or to suggest changes to intl, or to ICU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$b = '/var/www/libs/icudt48l';
$r = new \ResourceBundle('en_US', $b, true);
var_dump($r instanceof \ResourceBundle); //-> TRUE
```

the .dat extension should be left to make it work

Answer (score 0):

try `$resource = resourcebundle_create('en_US',$bundle,true);`

Comment: No success, tried;
resourcebundle_create();
new ResourceBundle();
ResourceBundle::create();

all return NULL...