# How do I create ICU resource files for use in PHP?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext, icu

I'm following the instructions from BryanH's answer here: [gettext() equivalent in Intl library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644412/gettext-equivalent-in-intl-library) and trying to implement localization (translation) with php-intl, but I keep getting the same problem this person had: [ResourceBundle returns NULL without any errors being raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256937/resourcebundle-returns-null-without-any-errors-being-raised)

He mentions he created the dat files with a tool (which I cannot figure out how to work) while the person in the former answer simply appears to be using txt files with a .res extension.

How do I properly implement localization with php-intl and ResourceBundle, and what am I doing wrong?

The goal is to have various data files with different languages so I can do something similar to

```
$t = new Translator();
$t->setResource(new \ResourceBundle('es', 'locales_folder/'));
$t->echo("somestring"); // "el stringo"
```

..much like the person in the first answer had. Also, the aim is to have easily editable files, so I can give them to translators for fixes, updates, and so on. I realize I could easily do this with custom solution through a simple text file which gets parsed and saved into memcache on first request, where it then persists and gets served from without having to re-read the .dat files, but I'd rather take the suggested route here.

Edit: Just to get it out there - I implemented the same thing with gettext successfully and it was dead easy - save for one bug that persists across linux systems (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#91187) - but I'd like to rely on the more modern and all-inclusive intl extension if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can provide a solution to your question on how to create and use `.res` files for the `intl` PHP extension, however I have no experience with speed and use in production systems, you will have to see for yourself if this can be a replacement for `gettext`.

In my opinion a great benefit of `gettext` are additional tools such as `xgettext` which can extract strings to be translated. Still, using resources might be more useful in your use-case.

To generate a `.res` file you need to use the program `genrb` which is [bundled with ICU](http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/browser/icu/trunk/source/tools/genrb/). (for example when installing ICU on OSX using `brew install icu4c` ([see this tutorial](http://darraghenright.tumblr.com/post/22027208929/installing-intl-package-on-osx-lion)) you can find the tool at `/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/*/bin/genrb` (replace `*` with the version number))

Next you prepare a file for each locale. Let's do this for two languages in this example, German and Spanish.

```
$ cat de.txt
de {
    hello { "Hallo" }
}

$ cat es.txt
es {
    hello { "Hola" }
}

$ genrb *.txt
genrb number of files: 2
```

You now have 2 additional files `de.res` and `es.res`, which you can now access in PHP

```
<?php
foreach (array("de", "es") as $locale) {
    $r = ResourceBundle::create($locale, __DIR__);
    echo $r["hello"], "\n";
}
```

which will output

```
Hallo
Hola
```

So in essence, you can hand those `*.txt` files to your translaters and prepare them for PHP using `genrb`.

Finally, a small example for the class you were trying to write:

```
<?php
class Translator {
    private $resourceBundle = null;

    public function __construct(\ResourceBundle $r) {
        $this->resourceBundle = $r;
    }

    public function __get($string) {
        return $this->resourceBundle[$string];
    }
}
$t = new Translator(new \ResourceBundle('es', __DIR__));
echo $t->hello;
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll do. Since this is supposed to be thread safe, I reckon it's the solution I was looking for. Now I'll just need to write my own string extractor and that should work.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could share you experience with it, also with your string extractor (maybe you could even open source it?). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since poedit can auto-extract for gettext, I figured I could just give it another pattern to look for like $t->_($string), which would then create .mo and .po files for those strings too. All I would have to do then is write a tool that converts those into RES format, which sounds fairly easy. I'll write a blog post about the entire ordeal and link it here.

Comment: @Swader ICU has tools that convert to and from XLIFF format. Could pivot through that as well. I've considered converting to and from po, mo, .properties, .rc, etc also.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'll be doing - converting from po files into res, seems the easiest since poedit so wonderfully extracts everything out of a project.